# Class & function/methods hierarchy tree based diagram

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plugins, pycharm, ide

I want to know if there are any software or IDE plugin or extension to view python projects class and methods hierarchy tree based diagram. More specifically is there any extension for visual studio code. As I am already aware of one in pycharm but I don't know whether it shows the project-based tree at once.
Thanks.

Comment: Please upvote this feature here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to see the hierarchy of classes and methods in Python files?

You could try to open OUTLINE in VScode. It will show you the classes and methods in the file layer by layer.And it is automatically generated.

[image: Screenshot].

Also, at the top of your code edit box, you could also view the class and method hierarchy diagram.
[image: Screenshot].

If these are not what you want, describe the details of your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I am looking for a tree-based diagram, as an ER diagram. But the ER diagram will be based on classes and methods and will show their relation with other classes and methods in a project directory.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use PlantUML. Reference:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.plantuml   Otherwise, I haven't found such an extension at the moment.